# Sql to get Status if it has more than one value

Tags: postgresql

Please let me know how can I bring back only the category and product only if all the status for the `CATEGORY` is Inactive, So if I have below:

```
CATEGORY  PRODUCT  STATUS    
10141     10094    Active
10141     20278    Active
10216     10163    Active
10217     10164    Inactive
00399     00308    Active
00399     01974    Inactive
00992     00822    Inactive    
00992     01399    Inactive
01720     01970    Inactive
```

I want to bring back:

```
CATEGORY  PRODUCT  STATUS    
10217     10164    Inactive
00992     00822    Inactive    
00992     01399    Inactive
01720     01970    Inactive
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT category, product FROM my_table WHERE status = 'Inactive';`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.   This will bring back CATEGORY 00399, this CATEGORY has STATUS that is Active and Inactive.  If it has ACTIVE as one of STATUS, I want to exclude it from the end result.  (I don't want to bring in both PRODUCT of 00308 and 01974 for CATEGORY 00399 because one of the STATUS is Active, if any of the STATUS for the CATEGORY is Active even though it has Inactive, I want to exclude these records)